# Is there a Zfill type function in micro python. Zfill in micro python

Tags: micropython

I am trying to put a python script on a pyboard that’s running micro python.  Is there a python equivalent of .zfill In MicroPython?

Answer (score 5):

there is no inbuilt zfill but I use this zfl function

```
def zfl(s, width):
# Pads the provided string with leading 0's to suit the specified 'chrs' length
# Force # characters, fill with leading 0's
return '{:0>{w}}'.format(s, w=width)
```

This might be useful to you? Just pass the string and the string width you require.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to  SO!

No, MicroPython does not have a zfill method on strings.

If you're looking for a specific width, you'll need to get a len(str) and then concatenate the desired string of "0"s to the start of string.